# Error that I must implement a function in a class even though function is defined

Tags: vb.net, class, interface, interface-implementation

I get the error: `Class 'QueryParameterComparer' must implement 'Function Compare(x As QueryParameter, y As QueryParameter) As Integer' for interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of QueryParameter)'.`

On this class definition:

```
    Protected Class QueryParameterComparer
        Implements IComparer(Of QueryParameter)

        Public Function Compare(x As QueryParameter, y As QueryParameter) As Integer
            If x.Name = y.Name Then
                Return String.Compare(x.Value, y.Value)
            Else
                Return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name)
            End If
        End Function

    End Class
```

I also tried writing it out fully:

```
    Protected Class QueryParameterComparer
        Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of QueryParameter)

        Public Function Compare(x As QueryParameter, y As QueryParameter) As Integer
            If x.Name = y.Name Then
                Return String.Compare(x.Value, y.Value)
            Else
                Return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name)
            End If
        End Function

    End Class
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Interface method implementation requires the *Implements* keyword.  Just let the IDE help you fall in the pit of success.  Delete the Function, put the cursor after the Implements yadayada line and press the Enter key.

Comment: Woah!  I've never seen that happen before!  I just marked this as a duplicate and then I realized that you were the one that asked the duplicate question years ago.  Funny...

Comment: @StevenDoggart: LOL! :S Some people never learn? :) Can't delete this post anymore though....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlike in c#, where the name of the method just has to match the one in the interface, in VB.NET, all interface implementations must always be explicitly stated with `Implements` keywords on each member:

```
Protected Class QueryParameterComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of QueryParameter)

    Public Function Compare(x As QueryParameter, y As QueryParameter) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of QueryParameter).Compare
        ' ...
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

VB.Net requires you to specify which methods are the implementation methods of your interfaces.

```
Public Function Compare(x As QueryParameter, y As QueryParameter) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of QueryParameter).Compare
```

It's odd, but it does allow for you to specify a different function name for the implementation.  This makes it so that a direct access to your class can have one name for the function, but a reference through the interface would have the interface method name.  Something else you can do is specify the method a Private so that you can only access the method through an interface reference.